# `docker run` as Prefect task

Tags: docker, prefect

My actual workloads that should be run as tasks within a Prefect flow are all packaged as docker images. So a flow is basically just "run this container, then run that container".

However, I'm unable to find any examples of how I can easily start a docker container as task. **Basically, I just need `docker run` from a flow.**

I'm aware of https://docs.prefect.io/api/latest/tasks/docker.html and tried various combinations of `CreateContainer` and `StartContainer`, but without any luck.

Answer (score 13):

Using the Docker tasks from Prefect's Task Library could look something like this for your use case:

```py
from prefect import task, Flow
from prefect.tasks.docker import (
    CreateContainer,
    StartContainer,
    GetContainerLogs,
    WaitOnContainer,
)

create = CreateContainer(image_name="prefecthq/prefect", command="echo 12345")
start = StartContainer()
wait = WaitOnContainer()
logs = GetContainerLogs()


@task
def see_output(out):
    print(out)


with Flow("docker-flow") as flow:
    container_id = create()
    s = start(container_id=container_id)
    w = wait(container_id=container_id)

    l = logs(container_id=container_id)
    l.set_upstream(w)

    see_output(l)

flow.run()
```

This snippet above will create a container, start it, wait for completion, retrieve logs, and then print the output of `echo 12345` to the command line.

Alternatively you could also use the Docker Python client directly in your own tasks https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#module-docker.api.container

Comment: This works, however it creates for tasks just to run one docker container. This makes large flows hard to manage. I guess I take the second route you suggested, like this I can create a single "docker run" task.

Comment: Hi @theDmi - you could merge them into one task via
```class MyTask(Task):
    def run(self, **kwargs):
        CreateContainer().run()
        StartContainer().run()
        WaitOnContainer().run()
```
(note this is pseudocode!)

Comment: @chriswhite I tried, but I always to some error like "no flow context found". Not sure if tasks can really be merged like that.

Comment: With prefect 2.2.0 this is no longer true. Can you provide this example but for prefect v2 @Josh